# laravel creating a helper

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have created file `helpers.php` (app/helpers.php)

```
function test($var)
{
    return $var;
}
```

I have changed app/start/global.php into

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/helpers.php',

));
```

Also composer.json into

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

But when am I trying to call this function inside controller

```
$data = Test::all();
return test($data);
```

It throws me an error

```
Call to undefined function test()
```

What's wrong?

Comment: it is telling the actual error..you are calling somewhere a method named 'pre_r'.

Comment: edited;sorry there should be test()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add -

```
require app_path().'/helpers.php';
```

at the end of - `app/start/global.php`
you dont have to add it to composer.json and set -

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

app_path().'/commands',
app_path().'/controllers',
app_path().'/models',
app_path().'/database/seeds',
));
```

hope this will work.

Comment: it's probably not the recommended way how to do that but at least it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

@sgt's approach works fine, but if you still want to use composer, use the `files` autoloader.

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "files": [
        "path/to/my/file.php"
    ]
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to `composer dump-autoload` after doing a change to the `autoload` directive.